# Accessing ASP.NET Sessions with HTML Page by Passing SessionID only through ajax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I am trying to convert an existing ASP.NET application to HTML Application for Phonegap. To achieve this I have to convert a major page i.e. Default.aspx to pure HTML page in order to package that application for Phonegap. Currently we have a login.aspx page hosted on some other server which authenticates user and redirects/posts the browser to Default.aspx with a page having all user data in it which we get in Page_PreInit method and load the rest of the Defalt.aspx page by saving everything in Session variable for later use and render the page accordingly. Sessions were previously managed by ASP.NET but once I will change Default.aspx to Default.html I might not be able to use that session variable.

1) Is there any possible way to use ASP.NET server side sessions by not using ASPX pages, means what if I save Session ID at client side and on every ajax request I obtain the Same Session by passing the Session ID with it to server? Is that possible?

2) Can I user WebAPI for initial parsing of post request from Login.aspx and save all that stuff to Session variable and render Default.html and save Current SessionID to HTML5 sessionstorage and use it later on with all requests?

Can someone guide me or give me a reference that I can get Server Sessions by passing only SessionID to it?

Comment: Why don't you use MVC for this? 1) You can access session state. 2) You can make the URL Default.html if you really want to. 3) You have complete control over the HTML. I can think of no reason why you would have to switch to static HTML just because you need control over your URL and markup.

Comment: is it possible to package all that stuff for phonegap? I know its a client side technology, and MVC routing stuff will work at server side but is it acceptable in phonegap builds specifically for iPhone Applications? because as per rule No 2.7 described by [link](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) it may conflict.